# Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Пройдя пешком за день более десяти километров, к вечеру вернулся на вокзал и… о, чудо: через пять минут уехал на отходящем поезде.  ***Еще вариант.*** Пройдя пешком за день более десяти километров, к вечеру вернулся на вокзал и… (о, чудо!): через пять минут уехал на отходящем поезде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чувства автора выражаются разными способами. Чаще всего используются вставные конструкции. Вот у Тургенева и Льва Толстого:

> Но — чудное дело! — превратившись в англомана, Павел Петрович стал в
> то же время патриотом (Т.)
>
> …Воображая, что замок заперт, я вынул ключ, и — о ужас! — у меня в
> руках была только головка ключика (Л.Т.)

*Пройдя пешком за день более десяти километров, к вечеру вернулся на вокзал и... - о чудо!- через пять минут уехал на отходящем поезде.*

Если очень хочется поставить многоточие - пусть остаётся для передачи эффекта неожиданности, но можно и без многоточия, а вот междометие О здесь  становится частицей и усиливает слово "чудо", поэтому запятая не нужна.

*Пройдя пешком за день более десяти километров, к вечеру вернулся на вокзал и… о, чудо: через пять минут уехал на отходящем поезде!*

Такая конструкция тоже возможна, если считать финальную часть неполным предложением, раскрывающим содержание слова "чудо", только восклицательный знак здесь тоже просится, если уж есть эмоциональная частица О. Это авторская пунктуация.